# Sort PHP Array using a function parameter sort number

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am building a PHP function to enqueue JavaScript files into a PHP array and then have another PHP function that will load all the JS files into a page and load them in the order based on a sort number that can be passed into the enqueue function.  Similar to how WordPress loads JS and CSS files.

So my PHP function `enqueue_js_script()` might look like this below which takes in a key name for the JS file, a file path to the JS file, and a sort order number which is optional.  It then would add the JS file to a PHP class property `$this->_js_files[$script_key]`...

```
public function enqueue_js_script($script_key, $file_source, $load_order = 0){
    $this->_js_scripts[$script_key] = $file_source;
}
```

Then I will also have a PHP function `load_js_scripts()` which will print each script file path into the header of a webpages HTML.

This is where I want to take into consideration the `$load_order` passed into `enqueue_js_script()` to print the scripts into the HTML in the order based on these numbers.

How can I use this sort order number to sort my array of JS scripts?

---

**UPDATE**

It looks like I should store the sort number in an array like this instead...

```
    $this->_js_files[$script_key] = array(
      'file_source' => $file_source,
      'sort' => $load_order
    );
```

Comment: To simplify your question, you are passing in a key, a value, and a sort order. You'll need to save your value and sort order in an object and write a custom sort function using usort http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: What's the purpose of `$script_key`? Can more than one script file be assigned to the same `$script_key`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using usort and a custom sorting function:

```
<?php 
public function enqueue_js_script($script_key, $file_source, $load_order = 0){
    $jsScript = new \stdClass;
    $jsScript->load_order = $load_order;
    $jsScript->script_key = $script_key;
    $this->_js_scripts[$script_key] = $jsScript;
}

function sortJSFiles($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->load_order == $b->load_order) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->load_order < $b->load_order) ? -1 : 1;
}


usort($this->_js_scripts, "sortJSFiles");
```

Answer (score 1):

Having to pass your array key is not really good practice. The `$array[] = $foo` construction adds `$foo` as the new last item of `$array`.

Using [usort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
<?php
class OrderStack {
    private $contents = array();
    public function add($order, $load) {
        if (!is_int($order) || $order < 0) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("$order must be a non-negative integer");
        }
        $this->contents[] = array($order, $load);
    }
    public function get_array() {
        usort(
            $this->contents,
            'OrderStack::compare'
        );
        return array_map(
            'OrderStack::get_load',
            $this->contents
        );
    }
    private static function get_load($stack_item) {
        return $stack_item[1];
    }
    private static function compare($a, $b) {
        return $a[0] - $b[0];
    }
}

class YourClass {
    private $_js_scripts;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_js_scripts = new OrderStack();
    }
    public function enqueue_js_script($file_source, $load_order = 0) {
        $this->_js_scripts->add($load_order, $file_source);
    }
    public function get_js_scripts() {
        return $this->_js_scripts->get_array();
    }
}
?>
```

The OrderStack class is reusable.